# Sending LWC Email Template

Tags: lightning-web-components, email-template, apex-email-service

We have a report that we currently generate using Conga (3rd party license), in the past we've made similar visual representations of the data using VisualForce, but now as we consider the possibilities of LWCs I'm curious if:

1) There's any reason we couldn't just make the HTML design necessary to make this report (Order(s) and Order details) within a LWC. This way it wouldn't require a license for a user to view this page and save as a PDF to send in an email.

2) Could the LWC representation of the data be sent in an email (embedded), preferably by APEX via the Order creation process when work order payload is submitted via APEX REST API (custom field service application).

If this can be done, are there any good known source that could help with the steps necessary to make this happen?